# Youtube video still playing after modal is closed--and I've tried every fix known to man with no luck!

Tags: javascript, modal-popup, modal, youtube

I'm having an issue with Youtube continuing to play after closing a modal. I know this is not a unique problem and I have done exhaustive research to find answers. Unfortunately nothing has worked. I have tried it all!

Here is what I currently have:

```
<div class="lightbox" id="box-books">
  <div class="box-bg">
   <a href="#page" class="close">X</a>
   <iframe id="playerid" class="center" width="80%" height="600px" 
   src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries? 
   list=PLUgadhOLCi0T6NfoVWSBOIsHbkhD_I8Vs" frameborder="0" 
   webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen 
   allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
 $('.action-close').on('click', function() {
  var video = $("#playerid").attr("src");
  $("#playerid").attr("src","");
  $("#playerid").attr("src",video);
 });
</script>
```

Any thoughts? At this point I am desperate and frustrated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $("#playerid").stopVideo(); does that function stop it?

Comment: Nope. The strange thing is, I was using the code below to cut off the audio for a soundsgood playlist and that was working just fine. But when I try to apply the same code to a youtube video, it fails.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not Magento related

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, using bootstrap thanks to some help from [this site](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-embed-youtube-video-inside-bootstrap-modal.php).

Here is the script:

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(function(){
  //Snag the URL of the iframe so we can use it later
  var url = $('.modal-body-music iframe').attr('src');

  $('.close').click(function() {
      $('.modal-body-music').hide();
    $('.modal-body-music iframe').attr('src', '');
  });

  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('.modal-body-music').show();
    $('.modal-body-music iframe').attr('src', url);
  });
});
});
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="box-music" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h2 align="center" class="lightbox-content">A Musical Moment</h2>       
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body-music">
                <div style="clear:both;margin-top:70px;">
                   https://open.spotify.com/playlist/5o8aJ6DCc1TGQ0o7LxP2uO
                   <br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can mark sure answer,  if its correct.